# "shinycssloaders" don't work with a button in observeEvent

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm new with shiny, but I would want to make a loader work while the action of a button is running.

My code is something like what is shown below:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(bslib)
library(DT)
library(shinycssloaders)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  
  theme = bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "sandstone"),
  
  titlePanel("TITLE"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("n", "n"),
      numericInput("m", "m"),
      numericInput("sigma", "sigma"),
      numericInput("S2", "S2"),
      numericInput("alpha", "alpha"),
      numericInput("lambda", "lambda"),
      numericInput("beta", "beta"),
      actionButton("runButton", "Run")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Results and chart", 
                 tableOutput("results"),
                 plotOutput("chart")),
        tabPanel(...)),
        
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  res <- reactiveValues(ults = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$runButton, {

 
  #Code with loops that generates a vector

  res$ults <- Vector
})

output$results <- renderTable({
      
    req(res$ults)
    
  }, rownames = FALSE, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
```

I've seen about the package called "shinycssloaders", so I tried:

```
mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Results and chart", 
                 shinycssloaders::withSpinner(tableOutput("results")),
                 plotOutput("chart")),
        tabPanel(...)),        
      )
```

and also:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  res <- reactiveValues(ults = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$runButton, {
  
  showPageSpinner()
 
  #Code with loops that generates a vector

  res$ults <- Vector

  hidePageSpinner()

})
```

However, neither worked...

The first way it seems that the loader appears during one second give or take, before pressing the button, and then it disappears... and in the second way, it seems that it doesn't even recognize the fucntion "showPageSpinner()".

I saw these options in this link: https://github.com/daattali/shinycssloaders

Does anyone know how to make it work?

Thank you!

Comment: You have `output$resultados` on the server side but `tableOutput("results")` on the ui side.  The output IDs should match.

Comment: Sorry! Actually I was translating the names of the variables and vectors to English too, but it seems I missed translating one of them... But in my code it matches. Sorry for that, and thank you for calling my attention to it.

Comment: I think I got it right now. Thanks.